# Unable to login as a vendor in django rest framework

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, permissions, multiple-users

I have three types of users in CustomUser model each provided with an integer value. Also, I have made a separate view for login for vendor.

I registered a user as vendor from default django admin. But I am unable to login as a vendor when I call the login as vendor api. I get the error message saying this is not a seller account.

My models:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="First name")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Last name")
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    Type_Choices = (
                (1, 'Customer'),
                (2, 'Vendor'),
                (3, 'Admin'),
            )
    user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=Type_Choices, default=1)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name"]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

My serializers:

```
 class CustomLoginSerializer(LoginSerializer):
    
    username = None
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(style={"input_type": "password"},)
    user_type = serializers.IntegerField()
```

My views:

```
class VendorLoginUserView(LoginView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = CustomLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        serializer = CustomLoginSerializer(data=data)
        data['user_type'] = request.user.user_type
        user_type = data['user_type']
        if user_type is 2:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            new_data = serializer.data
            user = serializer.validated_data["user"]
            serializer = self.get_serializer(user)
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            # return response.Response(new_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            return response.Response({"token": token.key,
                                      "serializer.data": serializer.data},
                                       status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
            message = "This is not a seller account"
            return Response({'message':message,},
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My urls:

```
path("api/vendorlogin/",views.VendorLoginUserView.as_view(), name='api-vendorlogin'),
```

Also, do I need to make a separate register view for vendor??

Comment: this line of your code `if user_type is 2:` it bothers me. please change it to `if user_type == 2`

Comment: I tried this, but it doesnt work as well. Same error.

Comment: did you add this at `settings.py` file `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.CustomUser'` ?